# Nifi site to site

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a site to site connection between 2 Nifi servers.
Nifi1 (Hostname wef2 - running on windows) need to deliver traffic to nifi2 (IP 10.168.233.168 - running on linux) - I defined the connection and all is green but on Nifi1 I'm getting the following error messages

*port ID 0176100c-8d25-196b-1f72-6befa5cab12a is the input port in NIFI2

```
**2020-12-01 01:54:13,508 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 2 records in 0 milliseconds
2020-12-01 01:54:20,677 INFO [Http Site-to-Site PeerSelector] o.apache.nifi.remote.client.PeerSelector Successfully refreshed peer status cache; remote group consists of 2 peers
2020-12-01 01:54:23,203 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Penalizing a peer Peer[url=http://localhost:8080/nifi-api] due to java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 404 errCode:Abort errMessage:Unable to find port with id '0176100c-8d25-196b-1f72-6befa5cab12a'.
2020-12-01 01:54:23,208 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Penalizing a peer Peer[url=http://wef2:8080/nifi-api] due to java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 404 errCode:Abort errMessage:Unable to find port with id '0176100c-8d25-196b-1f72-6befa5cab12a'.
2020-12-01 01:54:23,208 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Couldn't find a valid peer to communicate with.
2020-12-01 01:54:33,214 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Penalizing a peer Peer[url=http://wef2:8080/nifi-api] due to java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 404 errCode:Abort errMessage:Unable to find port with id '0176100c-8d25-196b-1f72-6befa5cab12a'.
2020-12-01 01:54:33,219 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Penalizing a peer Peer[url=http://localhost:8080/nifi-api] due to java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 404 errCode:Abort errMessage:Unable to find port with id '0176100c-8d25-196b-1f72-6befa5cab12a'.
2020-12-01 01:54:33,219 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Couldn't find a valid peer to communicate with.
2020-12-01 01:54:33,510 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2020-12-01 01:54:33,510 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 2 records in 0 milliseconds**
```

**Nifi 1**

[image: NIFI1]

**Nifi 2**

[image: NIFI2]

**remote process**

[image: remote process]

**remote process configuration**

[image: remote process configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the nifi.proporties file with the following parameters

Under # Site to Site properties section update the following lines 
nifi.remote.input.host =  
nifi.remote.input.socket.port= 10000